# Will an API call parse the body directly to the object if the [FromBody] tag is missing?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API route in .NET Core 3.1 that looks like this:

**public ActionResult dummyApi(string id,ObjectClass Object)**

And a URL that looks like this:

**randomurl/f77e2d72-18aa-ee11-8cc0-005056a76895?randomspecifiedfields**

Will this properly parse the ID from the query parameter, and the Object from the body?

**In this form it does not work, but when I add the [FromBody] qualifier before the second function argument it works.**

Any insight as to why, or if this is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I think this is to be expected; I believe the default is [FromUri] but I have an instance of a route having no Uri parameters where the controller method accepts the body via parameter, and it is working without a [FromBody] attribute (seemingly contradicting what I just said). It's probably wisest to attribute all your controller method parameters even if it is redundant.

Comment: I just realized you are referring to .NET Core where I was referring to .NET Framework WebAPI. There are many similarities and overlaps, but also differences.

Comment: Is this a GET endpoint? I would not expect anything in the body of a GET request. I think if you have a mix of arguments, you need some way of telling ASP.NET where it's supposed to look.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am more familiar with Framework, so this may not apply, but as I understand it, you don't have to be explicit if certain heuristics can be applied without ambiguity. For example: matching by parameter name between arguments in the route and arguments in the controller method. For a GET method, there is not normally a body, so all the controller method parameters should be supplied via the URI.

Answer (score 0):

Binding can be done in a few ways. Please look if you have an attribute like `[HttpGet("{id}")]` - this will bind the `id`.

There is also a default mapping order, and it is described in [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sources-2).

Comment: Please don't make your answer dependent on a link to another site. If the license of the other site allows, quote the relevant content here. See [How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing) and [answer].

Comment: @HereticMonkey That site is an official Microsoft documentation...

Comment: And Microsoft never changes their URLs?!?

Answer (score 0):

> Will an API call parse the body directly to the object if the
> [FromBody] tag is missing

--For controllers with [ApiController] attribute,Yes

> Will this properly parse the ID from the query parameter, and the
> Object from the body?

--Yes,[ApiController] won't bind simple types from requestbody

> In this form it does not work, but when I add the [FromBody] qualifier
> before the second function argument it works.

-- For controller without a [ApiController] attribute,you have to add [FromBody] attribute,otherwise it would read value from Request form by default

You may check this part of the  official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#binding-source-parameter-inference):

> The [ApiController] attribute applies inference rules for the default
> data sources of action parameters. These rules save you from having to
> identify binding sources manually by applying attributes to the action
> parameters. The binding source inference rules behave as follows:
>
> [FromServices] is inferred for complex type parameters registered in
> the DI Container. [FromBody] is inferred for complex type parameters
> not registered in the DI Container. An exception to the [FromBody]
> inference rule is any complex, built-in type with a special meaning,
> such as IFormCollection and CancellationToken. The binding source
> inference code ignores those special types. [FromForm] is inferred for
> action parameters of type IFormFile and IFormFileCollection. It's not
> inferred for any simple or user-defined types. [FromRoute] is inferred
> for any action parameter name matching a parameter in the route
> template. When more than one route matches an action parameter, any
> route value is considered [FromRoute]. [FromQuery] is inferred for any
> other action parameters.